# Prevent IKImageView from handling gestures

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, ikimageview

I have class `Canvas` and another custom view `CanvasItem` both subclasses of `NSView`. The `CanvasItem` has a `IKImageView` subview.

`Canvas` overrides `magnifyWithEvent` to react to the gesture. Everything works fine except the case when the gesture is done on one of the `CanvasItem`s then the `IKImageView` handles the event and zooms the image instead of passing it up the view hierarchy. Is here a way to prevent `IKImageView` from handling gestures?

I tried setting `editable` to `false` but with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me. In the end it was quite simple: I created a new subclass of `IKImageView` overwrote the `magnifyWithEvent` and passed the event to the next responder. And then used this class instead of the original `IKImageView`.

```
class MyIKImageView : IKImageView {
    override func magnifyWithEvent(event: NSEvent) {
        self.nextResponder?.magnifyWithEvent(event)
    }
}
```